# Why is this method to align textarea with its label working?

Tags: css, textarea, vertical-alignment

I found a [solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form#basic_form_styling) to align the top of textarea with the top of its label.

My question is: the `vertical-align` property of `<label>` is still the default value(baseline), so why we can align them on top just by setting the `vertical-align` property of `<textarea>` to `top`?

Thank you very much!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Active learning: Implementing our form HTML</title>
  <style>
    form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 500px;
      padding: 1em;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 1em;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    form li+li {
      margin-top: 1em;
    }

    label {
      width: 90px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: right;
    }

    input,
    textarea {
      font: 1em sans-serif;
      width: 300px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      outline: none;
    }

    input:focus,
    textarea:focus {
      border-color: #000;
    }

    img {
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 150px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    textarea {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="user_email" id="mail">
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="user_message" id="msg"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li class="button">
        <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't defined in the CSS specs. The label could be placed level with anywhere from the top to bottom of the textarea and all the constraints of the spec would be satisfied. This actually leads to an oddity. If the line contains a label and _two_ textareas, the first `vertical-align:top` and the second `vertical-align:bottom`, Firefox and Chromium disagree on where the label gets placed vertically.

Comment: Hi, @Alohci, thank you. It seems so. The CSS spec does not clearly stipulate how to align the textarea in the line box. If set `vertical-align: middle`, it seems to be consistent between the two browsers. It seems that this is one of the differences in browser implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: the vertical-align property of  is still the default value(baseline), so why we can align them on top just by setting the vertical-align property of  to top?

They are still aligned at the baseline but the visual result is the top.

By adding `vertical-align:top` to `<textarea>` this one is no more considered in the baseline alignment so only the label is concerned and since its the only element then it will set the baseline and will logically touch the top.

Here is an illustration to better understand:

```css
div {
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:4px
}
```

```html
The label is alone aligned at the baseline
<div>
  <label for="msg">Message:</label>
</div>
The baseline and top are the same
<div>
  <label for="msg" style="vertical-align:top">Message:</label>
</div>
Adding the textarea with vertical-align:top will not change the baseline. It will simply add the textarea at the top and expand the height
<div>
  <label for="msg">Message:</label>
  <textarea name="user_message" style="vertical-align:top"></textarea>
</div>
add another element aligned at the baseline and the label will get affected. The textarea is still at the top unaffected by the baseline
<div>
  <label for="msg">Message:</label>
  <span style="font-size:40px">AA</span>
  <textarea name="user_message" style="vertical-align:top"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

the default value for label, `vertical-align` is still `baseline`, so you need only to add this to your code:

```
 label {
      width: 90px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: right;
      vertical-align: top;
      
    }
```

If you wanna know more about it, you can find more information there: [w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp](http://w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)